# How to enable pycrust/pyshell when a modal dialog popup?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

We embedded wxPython to an existing c++ wxWidgets application. And use pycrust/pyshell to input python command to the application interactively. It works fine except that when the application pop up a modal dialog, we can not do any input in pycrust/pyshell. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a modal dialog it creates a temporary event loop which takes precedence over the application's main event loop, rather then calling the dialog with

```
ShowModal()
```

use

```
Show()
```

instead and then the main event loop will continue.